# What is this jQuery selector: a[@rel*=lightbox]?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am doing a bit of refactoring on some logic and i came across this chunk of code and i am still trying to understand it

```
  try {
   $('a[@rel*=lightbox]').lightBox(); 
  } catch (e) {}
```

I understand the try catch part but what is this part

```
('a[@rel*=lightbox]')
```

Comment: You *might* want to use `$('a[rel~=lightbox]').lightBox();` instead as the `~=` looks for the whole word `lightbox` instead of `*=`, which just finds a substring, e.g. "notalightbox" would be included in the `*=` method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is the old XPath way of saying *find anchors with `lightbox` in their `rel` attribute*. So it would match an anchor like the example below...

```
<a href="http://example.com/image.jpg" alt="image" rel="external me lightbox">Link</a>
```

It has been deprecated and removed from new versions of jQuery. To get it to work with the latest versions, just drop the `@`:

```
$('a[rel*=lightbox]')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an [Atrribute Contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) using deprecated `@` (XPath) syntax.

Answer (score 1):

There is a better way to write this selector.

```
$('img[rel="lightbox"]')
```

This will select any image tags with the relationship of "lightbox". You shouldn't need to do a try statement, if you've correctly included all your scripts it should work fine.

Comment: But it don't match rel="external me lightbox" as in @alex answer.

Comment: Then you can simply use *= like so: $('img[rel*="lightbox"]')

Answer (score 0):

It selects all links that contains lightbox in the attribute rel

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for links on the page that have somelink to launch a lightbox window.